# What kind of wood is 'Lava Burl' in Cajon?

Tags: drums, percussion, cajon

I was checking out on some cajons, and found the [Meinl Artisan Buleria Cajon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007PAC8H6). On its specs, I found that its body is made of birch, yet its frontplate is of 'Lava Burl'. What is this about? Is it a specific type of wood?

Comment: "Burl" simply means wood with a lot of knots, giving an irregular and decorative grain pattern. It is often cut from the base of a tree where the trunk joins the roots. Because of the irregular grain, it's not much use for anything *except* decoration. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burl I've no idea what "Lava burl" is specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of Meinl,the short answer is that 'lava' refers to a colour and not a timber. The timber is most probably what Meinl calls 'siam oak', which is rubber wood. If you go through the Meinl site, you will see terms like 'desert burl' and notice that the timber is , once again, 'siam oak'.